# How to combine jQuery DataTables and the PagingAndSorting Repository in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, datatables, pagination

I want to sort and filter data from a MySQL DB with the DataTables library, however, I would like to use the Spring paging and sorting repository for pagination. Why? because I'm of the belief that the DataTables library would load all the data from the db at once thus increasing loading times. I want to use Spring to load a specified number of data entries at once for faster loading times.

For example: If the database has 100k entries to load all of that at once would result in slow loading speeds, but if I were to implement paging with spring and only load 10 per tab, speeds would be faster. So if I'm on page one of the list, the data on page two isn't loaded until a button like `next` or `2` is clicked.

I have a working project in which I did sorting, filtering and paging with the Spring repository, I'll include some of the necessary code now:

**The following is the service interface methods:**

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;

import net.javaguides.springboot.model.Employee;

public interface EmployeeService {

    List<Employee> findAll(String keyword);

    List<Employee> getAllEmployees();

    void saveEmployee(Employee employee);

    Employee getEmployeeById(long id);

    void deleteEmployeeById(long id);

    Page<Employee> findPaginated(int pageNo, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortDirection);

    Page<Employee> searchEmployees(int pageNo, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortDir, String keyword);
}
```

**This is the implementations of the methods:**

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import net.javaguides.springboot.model.Employee;
import net.javaguides.springboot.repository.EmployeeRepository;

@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Employee> findAll(String keyword) {
        return employeeRepository.findAll(keyword);
    }

    public Employee get(Long id) {
        return employeeRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        return employeeRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }

    @Override
    public Employee getEmployeeById(long id) {
        Optional<Employee> optional = employeeRepository.findById(id);
        Employee employee = null;
        if (optional.isPresent()) {
            employee = optional.get();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(" Employee not found for id :: " + id);
        }
        return employee;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEmployeeById(long id) {
        this.employeeRepository.deleteById(id);
    }



    public Page<Employee> findPaginated(int pageNo, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortDirection) {
        Sort sort = sortDirection.equalsIgnoreCase(Sort.Direction.ASC.name()) ? Sort.by(sortField).ascending() :
            Sort.by(sortField).descending();
        
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo - 1, pageSize, sort);
        return this.employeeRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }

    public Page<Employee> searchEmployees(int pageNo, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortDir, String keyword) {
        Sort sort = Sort.by(sortField);
        sort = sortDir.equals("asc") ? sort.ascending() : sort.descending();

        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo - 1, pageSize, sort);

        Page<Employee> page;
        if (keyword != null && !keyword.isEmpty()) {
            page = employeeRepository.findByFirstNameContainingOrLastNameContaining(keyword, keyword, pageable);
        } else {
            page = employeeRepository.findAll(pageable);
        }

        return page;
    }
}
//This is the entire Service class
```

**This is the controller class:**

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import net.javaguides.springboot.model.Employee;
import net.javaguides.springboot.service.EmployeeService;

@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;
    
    // display list of employees
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model, @Param("keyword") String keyword) {
        return findPaginated(1, "firstName", "asc", keyword, model);
    }

    @GetMapping("/showNewEmployeeForm")
    public String showNewEmployeeForm(Model model) {
        // create model attribute to bind form data
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        return "new_employee";
    }

    @PostMapping("/saveEmployee")
    public String saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee) {
        // save employee to database
        employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @GetMapping("/showFormForUpdate/{id}")
    public String showFormForUpdate(@PathVariable ( value = "id") long id, Model model) {

        // get employee from the service
        Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployeeById(id);

        // set employee as a model attribute to pre-populate the form
        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        return "update_employee";
    }

    @GetMapping("/deleteEmployee/{id}")
    public String deleteEmployee(@PathVariable (value = "id") long id) {
        // call delete employee method
        this.employeeService.deleteEmployeeById(id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }


    @GetMapping("/page/{pageNo}")
    public String findPaginated(@PathVariable (value = "pageNo") int pageNo,
                                @RequestParam(value = "sortField") String sortField,
                                @RequestParam(value = "sortDir", defaultValue = "asc") String sortDir,
                                @RequestParam(value = "keyword", required = false) String keyword,
                                Model model) {
        int pageSize = 10;
        Sort.Direction direction = Sort.Direction.ASC;
        Page<Employee> page;
        if (keyword != null && !keyword.isEmpty()) {
            page = employeeService.searchEmployees(pageNo, pageSize, sortField, sortDir, keyword);
        } else {
            page = employeeService.findPaginated(pageNo, pageSize, sortField, sortDir);
        }
        List<Employee> listEmployees = page.getContent();

        model.addAttribute("currentPage", pageNo);
        model.addAttribute("totalPages", page.getTotalPages());
        model.addAttribute("totalItems", page.getTotalElements());

        model.addAttribute("sortField", sortField);
        model.addAttribute("sortDir", sortDir);
        model.addAttribute("keyword", keyword);
        model.addAttribute("reverseSortDir", sortDir.equals("asc") ? "desc" : "asc");

        model.addAttribute("listEmployees", listEmployees);
        return "index";
    }

}
```

**Lastly, the HTML markup:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-pumBsjNRGGqkPzKHndZMaAG+bir374sORyzM3uulLV14lN5LyykqNk8eEeUlUkB3U0M4FApyaHraT65ihJhDpQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container my-2">
    <h1>Employees List</h1>
        <form th:action="@{/}">
            Filter: <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" size="50" th:value="${keyword}" required />
            &nbsp;
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            &nbsp;
            <input type="button" value="Clear" id="btnClear" onclick="clearSearch()" />
        </form>
        Sort by email: <form th:action="@{/page/1}" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" name="sortField" value="email"/>
            <input type="radio" name="sortDir" value="asc" th:checked="${sortDir=='asc'}" onchange="this.form.submit()"/> Ascending
            <input type="radio" name="sortDir" value="desc" th:checked="${sortDir=='desc'}" onchange="this.form.submit()"/> Descending
        </form>
        <br>
        Sort by lastname: <form th:action="@{/page/1}" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" name="sortField" value="lastName"/>
            <input type="radio" name="sortDir" value="asc" th:checked="${sortDir=='asc'}" onchange="this.form.submit()"/> Ascending
            <input type="radio" name="sortDir" value="desc" th:checked="${sortDir=='desc'}" onchange="this.form.submit()"/> Descending
        </form>
        <br>
        Sort by firstname: <form th:action="@{/page/1}" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" name="sortField" value="firstName"/>
            <input type="radio" name="sortDir" value="asc" th:checked="${sortDir=='asc'}" onchange="this.form.submit()"/> Ascending
            <input type="radio" name="sortDir" value="desc" th:checked="${sortDir=='desc'}" onchange="this.form.submit()"/> Descending
        </form>

        <a th:href = "@{/showNewEmployeeForm}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3"> Add Employee </a><br>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="female-checkbox">
            <label for="female-checkbox">Show All Employees</label>
        </div>
        <table border="1" class = "table table-striped table-responsive-md">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <a th:href="@{'/page/' + ${currentPage} + '?sortField=firstName&sortDir=' + ${reverseSortDir}}">
                        Employee First Name</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    <a th:href="@{'/page/' + ${currentPage} + '?sortField=lastName&sortDir=' + ${reverseSortDir}}">
                            Employee Last Name</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    <a th:href="@{'/page/' + ${currentPage} + '?sortField=email&sortDir=' + ${reverseSortDir}}">
                            Employee Email</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Gender
<!--                        <label for="showFemaleEmployeesCheckbox">Show Female Employees</label>-->
<!--                        <input type="checkbox" onchange="showAll()" id="showAllCheckbox"> Show all genders-->
                    </th>
                    <th> Actions </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr th:each="employee : ${listEmployees}">
                <td th:text="${employee.firstName}"></td>
                <td th:text="${employee.lastName}"></td>
                <td th:text="${employee.email}"></td>
                <td th:text="${employee.gender}"></td>
                <td>
                    <a th:href="@{/showFormForUpdate/{id}(id=${employee.id})}" class="btn btn-primary">Update</a>
                    <a th:href="@{/deleteEmployee/{id}(id=${employee.id})}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div th:if = "${totalPages > 1}">
            <div class = "row col-sm-10">
                <div class = "col-sm-2">
                    Total Rows: [[${totalItems}]]
                </div>
                <div class = "col-sm-1">
                    <span th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(1, totalPages)}" style="display: flex;">
                        <a th:if="${currentPage != i}" th:href="@{'/page/' + ${i}+ '?sortField=' + ${sortField} + '&sortDir=' + ${sortDir}}">[[${i}]]</a>
                        <span th:unless="${currentPage != i}">[[${i}]]</span>  &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class = "col-sm-1">
                    <a th:if="${currentPage < totalPages}" th:href="@{'/page/' + ${currentPage + 1}+ '?sortField=' + ${sortField} + '&sortDir=' + ${sortDir}}">Next</a>
                    <span th:unless="${currentPage < totalPages}">Next</span>
                </div>

                 <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <a th:if="${currentPage < totalPages}" th:href="@{'/page/' + ${totalPages}+ '?sortField=' + ${sortField} + '&sortDir=' + ${sortDir}}">Last</a>
                    <span th:unless="${currentPage < totalPages}">Last</span>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

With the code I sent you should be able to use Paging, Sorting and Filtering with the PagingAndSorting Repository from Spring boot.

To re-iterate, I want to use the PagingAndSorting repository to only use pagination in order to load data on the server side and not on the front-end, but still continue to use the DataTables for searching and sorting. I'm aware that the DataTables library can load the data on the server-side, but does that mean that the data in only loaded when it requested? i.e. clicking `next` or `previous` etc.

Comment: Yes that is correct: use the `serverSide: true` option. An overview of how that works is here: [Server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side). **Whenever a user performs a filter, sort or page change action in DataTables, DataTables will automatically generate the correct Ajax request** to the server. The Ajax response must conform to the expected [JSON structure](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Example-data). Only 1 page of data is needed.

Comment: Update: I'm allowed to use the jQuery lib for server-side processing, however, I was alerted to the fact that the issue is that I'm stilling loading all the data entries when I use the .findAll() `public List<Employee> findAll(String keyword);`method in the repository, is there a way to only pull like 10 data entries at a time on the controller method?

Comment: "_is there a way to only pull like 10 data entries at a time on the controller method?_" - That sounds like a much more focused question than the original one. DataTables is irrelevant for this new question - it's more a Spring Data question (I think). Personally, I would probably not try to use Spring's `Page` or `Pageable` for this - because you also need to account for filtering (as well as pagination and sorting). But someone with deeper understanding of Spring's `Page` or `Pageable` may be able to help (where I fail - sorry).